# Selecting characters from command and replacing some of them

Tags: python, replace, netapp

I have this result from a NetApp query

```
Object: nfsv4_diag
Instance: nfs4_diag
Start-time: 6/4/2020 16:55:40
End-time: 6/4/2020 16:55:40
Scope: NODE1

Counter                                                     Value
-------------------------------- --------------------------------
storePool_ByteLockAlloc                                         0
storePool_ClientAlloc                                          60
storePool_CopyStateAlloc                                        0
storePool_DelegAlloc                                            0
storePool_DelegStateAlloc                                       0
storePool_LayoutAlloc                                           0
storePool_LayoutStateAlloc                                      0
storePool_LockStateAlloc                                        0
storePool_OpenAlloc                                            86
storePool_OpenStateAlloc                                       86
storePool_OwnerAlloc                                           10
storePool_StringAlloc                                          70

Object: nfsv4_diag
Instance: nfs4_diag
Start-time: 6/4/2020 16:55:40
End-time: 6/4/2020 16:55:40
Scope: NODE2

Counter                                                     Value
-------------------------------- --------------------------------
storePool_ByteLockAlloc                                      1246
storePool_ClientAlloc                                          29          
storePool_CopyStateAlloc                                        0          
storePool_DelegAlloc                                            0          
storePool_DelegStateAlloc                                       0          
storePool_LayoutAlloc                                           0          
storePool_LayoutStateAlloc                                      0          
storePool_LockStateAlloc                                      468          
storePool_OpenAlloc                                           811          
storePool_OpenStateAlloc                                      811          
storePool_OwnerAlloc                                          519          
storePool_StringAlloc                                         548          

Object: nfsv4_diag                                                             
Instance: nfs4_diag                                                            
Start-time: 6/4/2020 16:55:40                                                  
End-time: 6/4/2020 16:55:40                                                    
Scope: NODE3 



Counter                                                     Value          
-------------------------------- --------------------------------          
storePool_ByteLockAlloc                                       165          
storePool_ClientAlloc                                          27          
storePool_CopyStateAlloc                                        0          
storePool_DelegAlloc                                            0          
storePool_DelegStateAlloc                                       0          
storePool_LayoutAlloc                                           0          
storePool_LayoutStateAlloc                                      0          
storePool_LockStateAlloc                                      135          
storePool_OpenAlloc                                           272          
storePool_OpenStateAlloc                                      272          
storePool_OwnerAlloc                                          152          
storePool_StringAlloc                                         179
```

And I would like to transform it to something like:

```
NODE1.storePool_ByteLockAlloc=0;NODE1.storePool_ClientAlloc=60;NODE1.storePool_CopyStateAlloc=0;............NODEn.storePool_ByteLockAlloc=165;
```

For all the nodes I have from the output (not only 3).

I have tried replacing the output using this:

```
output.replace(' ', '').replace('Alloc', 'Alloc=').replace('\r','').replace('\n',' ')
```

But this is not giving me the result that I need.

Some ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: What API do you use to get this output? In what format do you get it (type of the object)?

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Also repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: From what you posted, it seems that you have a large text object, which you expect to magically parse into an unspecified data structure, through the application of a few simple replace commands.  I'm not at all clear how you anticipate this doign what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you capture the output into one long string, you can use a regex to find the lines of interest and parse them into the format you're requesting:

```
import re

output = """
Object: nfsv4_diag
Instance: nfs4_diag
Start-time: 6/4/2020 16:55:40
End-time: 6/4/2020 16:55:40
Scope: NODE1

Counter                                                     Value
-------------------------------- --------------------------------
storePool_ByteLockAlloc                                         0
storePool_ClientAlloc                                          60
storePool_CopyStateAlloc                                        0
storePool_DelegAlloc                                            0
.
.
.
"""

rv = []
current_node = None

for match in re.findall(r'Scope: (NODE\d+)|(storePool_.*)', output):
    node, metric = match
    if node and current_node != node:
        current_node = node

    if current_node and metric:
        name, value = metric.strip().split()
        rv.append(f'{current_node.strip()}.{name}={value}')

print(';'.join(rv))
```

Output:

```
NODE1.storePool_ByteLockAlloc=0;NODE1.storePool_ClientAlloc=60;NODE1.storePool_CopyStateAlloc=0;NODE1.storePool_DelegAlloc=0;...
```

Comment: For Python 2.7:

`rv = {}
current_node = None

for match in re.findall(r'Scope: (ESJC.*\d+)|(storePool_.*)', output):
    node, metric = match
    if node and current_node != node:
        current_node = node

    if current_node and metric:
        name, value = metric.strip().split()
        rv[current_node.strip() + "." + name + "=" + value] = [value]
print(';'.join(rv))`